# how to make custom directive in angular for calculate the distance using google maps

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, angularjs-directive

I want to make a directive of the function to calculate the distance by using google maps. i'm using angularjs and ionic for this project,but when i make this code, i get an error. here is the code.

```
var control = angular.module('starter.controllers', []);

control.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope,$http, $ionicPopup, $timeout,$ionicModal) {
    $scope.ori = "-7.048443, 110.441022";
    $scope.dest = "-7.048264, 110.440388";
});

control.directive('distance', function () {
    var calcRoute = function(ori,dest,cb) {
        var dist;
        var directionsDisplay;
        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
        directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
    var request = {
        origin:ori,
        destination:dest,
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
    };
    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            cb(null, response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value / 1000);
        }
        else {
            cb("error");
        }
     });
    };
    return{
        restrict:"E",
        scope: {
            ori: "@",
            dest:"@"
        },
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {
        var ori = attrs.ori;
        var dest = attrs.dest;
        calcRoute(ori,dest, function (err, dist) {
            if (!err) {
              console.log(dist);
            }else{
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
      }
    };
});
```

in my **View** file :

```
<distance ori='"{{ori}}"' dest='"{{dest}}"'></distance>
```

and the error on the console is :

```
Uncaught InvalidValueError: in property origin: not a string; and not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: not an Object
```

i don't understand what is the meaning of the error, anyone help me please, explain to me what is wrong with the code. thank you :)

Comment: Try `<distance ori="{{ori}}" dest="{{dest}}"></distance>`

Comment: @JqueryKing thanks for the answer, i have tried it but still get the same error.

Comment: did you try logging your origin? make sure your calcRoute is receiving the correct values (try console logging or alerting ori and dest in the first line of calcRoute). And also your request object. You should also check type.

Comment: @so_jin_ee i tried it too, logging **ori** and **dest** show correct values and the `typeof` show 'string'.logging the request show me following result, `Object {origin: "string", destination: "string", travelMode: "DRIVING"}` . but it still doesn't work, there are other solutions for this ? thanks :D

Comment: try logging request.origin. does it return a lat/long or is it empty string?

Comment: @so_jin_ee it return a LatLng instead of a string.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this

```
travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
```

should be this?

```
google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
```

as per this link?

[Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions)

**UPDATE**

Try this

In this HTML snippet

```
<distance ori='"{{ori}}"' dest='"{{dest}}"'></distance>
```

you have ori='"{{ori}}"' ( as well as dest ) both contain double sets of quotations. This results in a string inside the directive that looks like this...

```
"-7.048443, 110.441022"
```

Which **IS** a string, however it's a string with the characters " and " at the beginning and the end. I think your **ori** and **dest** should both not have double quotes as they are still strings when they arrive at the Google API, but in this case they arrive with characters that the Google API is most likely not allowing. The Google Map API would most likely like a string like this...

```
-7.048443, 110.441022 NOT THIS "-7.048443, 110.441022"
```

or if you printed them out in the console would look like this

```
"-7.048443, 110.441022" (good) ""-7.048443, 110.441022"" (bad)
```

In the (bad) case if you did this

```
console.log(ori[0])
```

you would get the first char of the (bad) string which is " It should instead be -

So you get an error for **origin** because the API fails on the first code. I think that if you corrected **ori** to this instead...

```
<distance ori="{{ori}}" dest='"{{dest}}"'></distance>
```

with only a single set of quotes, then **dest** would fail for the same reason.

Ultimately, I think changing your HTML snippet to this will result in correct execution...

```
<distance ori="{{ori}}" dest="{{dest}}"></distance>
```

Let us know if this works...

Comment: i think it's not the problem, like i mentioned above in the comment `travelMode` return correct value. but i'll try this..thanks :D

Comment: thanks for the update, your suggestion is almost the same as **JqueryKing** suggestion on the comment above, i tried it with double quotes but it still doesn't work..when i used single quotes, **it works**..I really don't know what actually happened, but thank you all for helping me.. :))